# Serialize hibernate foreign key values instead of pojos with gson

Tags: java, json, hibernate, foreign-keys, gson

I am trying to serialize hibernate objects using gson. When I do, I get something like this:

**User Object with Embedded Address Object**

```
{ "userName" : "melchoir",
   "address" : {}
}
```

That's cool and all, but I want something simpler. I want a more accurate representation of the database object. Specifically, I want to see the foreign key for the address rather than the actual address object. I want something like this:

**User Object with Foreign Key**

```
{"userName" : "melchoir",
       "addressId" : 3
}
```

Does anyone know how I can go about getting the second example out of gson and hibernate? I should point out that the hibernate objects have already been loaded. I cannot easily make another hibernate session with different configuration options just to satisfy this. I need a solution which rests with gson.

Comment: Try to get only foreign key values of Address Object in User Object in first place.. Anyway show your code how you are getting the data of user object.

Comment: @Babel That's a great idea. Unfortunately that is itself something I'm having trouble with. I have created a related stack overflow post here which investigates including the foreign keys on the objects when they are originally generated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34301634/eclipse-hibernate-pojo-generation-include-foreign-keys/34302239#34302239